# Discord.py constantly edit message

Tags: python, loops, discord, bots

Ok so I've created a bot with python and have set it so its always up and everything, but I want to make a message that it constantly sets to the current user count in the server.

I have no idea as to how I would do this, and appreciate any help I could get. I have got the message id, the channel id, and the guild id, I just need to know how to edit messages and how to do it every 10 seconds or so.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from discord.ext import commands
from typing import Union
import asyncio
import discord

_CH = Union[discord.TextChannel, discord.VoiceChannel, discord.CategoryChannel]
_C = commands.Context


class StatusCog(commands.Cog):
    INTERVAL = 60
    TEMPLATE = 'Online: {}, All: {}'

    def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.running = False
        self.STATUS_DICT = {'online': 0, 'offline': 0, 'idle': 0, 'dnd': 0}

    @commands.group(invoke_without_command=True)
    async def count(self, ctx: _C):
        pass

    @count.command()
    async def start(self, ctx: _C, channel: _CH):
        self.running = True
        while self.running:
            status = self.STATUS_DICT.copy()
            for member in ctx.guild.members:
                s = member.status
                for key in status.keys():
                    if getattr(s, key, False):
                        status[key] += 1
                        break
            await channel.edit(name=self.TEMPLATE[:].format(list(status.values())))
            await asyncio.sleep(self.INTERVAL)

    @count.command()
    async def stop(self, ctx: _C):
        self.running = False


def setup(bot: commands.Bot):
    bot.add_cog(Cog(bot))
```